# How to handle paging in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paging

I'm using asp.net mvc. I want to add paging to the list of records. Please help with any links or sample code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Paging with ASP.NET MVC Demo](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [taiga.nl](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/wp-content/uploads/subtext/WindowsLiveWriter/PagingwithASP.NETMVC_D952/aspnetmvc-pager_2.png))</sub>

Comment: The link no longer works. It returns a 404. Please update the link or provide an alternative answer.